# How to convert json string into normal string?

Tags: python, json, datetime, python-2.7, python-dateutil

I had an earlier question, which I have deleted in favour of this one. Since I was under the wrong assumption that it had something to do with the dateutil version.

```
test1 = dateutil.parser.parse("2013-01-24T16:50:42+00:00")
```

this works fine and I get a datetime.

But

```
dthandler = lambda obj: obj.isoformat() if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime) else None
test2 =  json.dumps(event.due_date_time, default=dthandler)
```

`print test2` --> `"2013-01-24T16:50:42+00:00"`

This looks to me like a normal string

```
test3 = dateutil.parser.parse(test2)
```

This crashes saying `ValueError: unknown string format`

So how do I convert json string into 'normal' string?

Comment: Why downvote and close without even leaving a comment behind? If anything is wrong with the question, I can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting that JSON puts quotes around the string. You have the following value:

```
jsonvalue = '"2013-01-24T16:50:42+00:00"'
```

Note the *double quotes* there.

You'd need to load that value using the `json.loads()` method again, which in this case just removes the quotes again:

```
>>> print json.loads(jsonvalue)
2013-01-24T16:50:42+00:00
```

Note that now the quotes are gone again. You could also just strip the quotes with `.strip('"')` if you have a mix:

```
>>> print jsonvalue.strip('"')
2013-01-24T16:50:42+00:00
```

but since you are expecting JSON data, why not just *treat it as json data* and use the `json` module for this to turn it back to Python data.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are *in* the string (print doesn't add them).

So `test3 = dateutil.parser.parse(test2[1:-1])` will work.